# Is the "Android taste test" only for certain models?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, launcher

Is the [#myandroid taste test](https://www.android.com/myandroid/) only for certain models?

I own a Pixel 5". Where do I find this info out?

Comment: How do you define "for certain models"? Do you mean the compatibility of app selections, or the test page itself?

Comment: Yes, the compatibility of the apps.  I tried ADI for Google Pixel launcher, it was early access invite/beta.  Could not gain root permission.  This is why I asked. @AndyYan